# How do I place a progress bar and button aligned with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried different options but I can't seem to line these up.  Any ideas?

```
<div class="row"> 
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="55%" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:55%">
                55%<span class="sr-only">55% Complete</span>
            </div>

        </div>
        <button style="margin-left: 20px; float:right;" type="button" class="btn-sm btn-danger">DANGER</button>

    </div>
</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For your code, just add `col-md-10` to progressbar. But I don't recommend your current structure. No need to create a nested row.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="progress col-md-10">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="55%" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:55%">
          55%<span class="sr-only">55% Complete</span>
        </div>

      </div>
      <button style="margin-left: 20px; float:right;" type="button" class="btn-sm btn-danger">DANGER</button>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

**Output:**

[image: Lineup]
[**CodePly**](http://www.codeply.com/go/8LjXCwKu4h)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are trying to line them up but I think this is more what you want

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-8">
                PROGRESS BAR GOES HERE
           </div>
           <div class="col-sm-4">
                BUTTON GOES HERE
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
        NOT SURE WHY YOU HAVE COL-MD-4 HERE BUT IF YOU WANT THAT DISPLAYED IT GOES HERE
   </div>
```